# Accessing data("") from dynamically created list items

Tags: jquery, dynamic

jQuery 2.2.3

I have a **dynamic** list of elements, that get created/removed on the fly:

```
<ul id="tracks">
    <button class="createRace" data-trackcode="410243">Create Race</button>
    <button class="createRace" data-trackcode="123540">Create Race</button>
    ...
</ul>
```

I am using the following technique to react to button clicks.

```
$("#tracks").on("click", ".createRace", createRaceClick);
```

My `createRaceClick()` function is being called, but the "**this**" object is referencing `#tracks`, not the `button` that was pressed.

How can I determine which button was pressed?  Or more specifically, how can I get the `data("trackcode")` associated with the actual button that was pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is strange, since in that context of event delegation, `this`  should refer to the `button` that was `clicked`. However you can use `target` property of the `event object` to get the `.createRace` that raised the click `event`:

```
$("#tracks").on("click", ".createRace", createRaceClick);

function createRaceClick(e){

  var data=$(e.target).data('trackcode'); //  $(this).data('trackcode') should work
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked perfectly.  I think because $("#tracks") has the "on" attached, then that is the context passed into the event function.